# How to speed up the response time of a button that uses an http Client

Tags: android, arduino

I'm currently having a project regarding an android program that could control arduino with ethernet shield and its primary goal is to turn on/off home devices. The android program have defined buttons that changes depending on the current state of devices. The project is almost done but the only problem is that the response time of some buttons when being pressed are delayed but some aren't. This project is very important so please kindly help me guys.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myhome_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    kitchenLight = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.kitchenLight);
    kitchenLight.setOnClickListener(this);
    livingLight = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.livingLight);
    livingLight.setOnClickListener(this);
    garageLight = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.garageLight);
    garageLight.setOnClickListener(this);
    diningLight = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.diningLight);
    diningLight.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void commandArduino(String url) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (kitchenLight.isChecked()) {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lighton1");
    } else {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lightoff1");
    }

    if (livingLight.isChecked()) {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lighton2");
    } else {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lightoff2");
    }

    if (garageLight.isChecked()) {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lighton3");
    } else {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lightoff3");
    }

    if (diningLight.isChecked()) {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lighton4");
    } else {
        commandArduino("http://192.168.1.102/?lightoff4");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of four separate calls just do one call like `http://192.168.1.102/?lighton1&lightoff2&lightoff3&lighton4`.

Comment: `new DefaultHttpClient();`. Is that your AsyncTask class?

Comment: @greenapps No, I think I don't have any AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem because you're making the HTTP requests on the UI thread of your application.   Generally you don't want to do any synchronous/blocking IO on the UI thread, because it makes your app unresponsive and can trigger the dreaded Application Not Responding dialog.

Android provides a simple solution to this problem in the form of the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.  In your case you won't even need to worry about params or results, since it would seem that you're OK with a fire and forget HTTP request, and you can simply pass the `HttpGet` instance to the `AysncTask`'s constructor.

To get you started, you can define a subclass of `AsycnTask` like this:

```
public static class CommandArduino extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   private HttpUriRequest mRequest;

   public CommandArduino( HttpUriRequest request ){
       mRequest = request;
   }

   protected Void doInBackground( Void... ignore ){
       new DefaultHttpClient().execute( mRequest );
       return null;
   }
}
```

Then you can replace your `commandArduino` method with something like:

```
new CommandArduino(new HttpGet(url)).execute();
```

One thing to note about this example is the use of the Void class to indicate that we don't care about parameters, progress, or results.  Normally you would do something like having these type parameters be something like `<URL, Integer, Integer>` so that you can pass in a `URL`, show progress using the `Integers`, and get the HTTP status code as an `Integer` (or something along those lines).

Comment: thanks for the answer but there's an error on the mRequest execution.

Comment: Error:(93, 36) java: no suitable method found for execute(org.apache.http.HttpRequest)
    method org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.apache.http.HttpRequest cannot be converted to org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)
    method org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<T>execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler<? extends T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T

Comment: @JethroMonzada my bad, you will have to change the type of mRequest to HttpUriRequest.  HttpGet implements this interface so the rest of your code should be ok.  See the edit in my reply.

Comment: You can find the JavaDocs for org.apache.http (where all of this stuff lives) here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/overview-summary.html